# How to Jest test a static method in node.js using variable defined outside class

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

Hi I have following code, and now I am not able to jest test the following in test class-
In below code, there is secret variable defined outside class and I want to test getSecrt method in jest test class, but i can only check for null condition(by default for any test case I write its returning null), but how to assign something to secret and check if condition too

```
// vault.js class
let secret;
class vaultclass {
  static getSecrt(key) {
    if (secret) {
      return secret[key];
    } else return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not add the `secret` as a static property on the class? `secret` is a dependency of the `Vault` so you should it pass it to the class itself during instantiation or set it as a static property.

Comment: @AbrarHossain If I make it static variable of class then we can easily modify it within our code base anyhwere like VaultClass.secret = "random_value". Not safe correct ?

Comment: Javascript does not have any access modifiers like `private` such that you can prevent this from being changed. The better option will be declare the secret as an environment variable and load it when your app starts. You can then pass to value to your `Vault` constructor (in that case, it should not be static). You can also look into dependency injection and containers like this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsyringe?activeTab=readme